# Changing the configuration of an already-built kernel and recompiling only what's been changed

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The scenario outlined is this:

- Someone has built the Linux kernel from source code.
- That person wants to change the build configuration.
- They still have all of the object files and temporary files that were produced by the previous build operation.

Given all of that, what needs to be done to rebuild as few things as possible in order to save time?

I understand that these will trigger or necessitate a complete recompilation of the source code:

- Running `make clean`.
- Running `make menuconfig`.

`make clean` is an obvious course of action to avoid to achieve the desired goal because it deletes all object files, both those that would need to be rebuilt and those that could otherwise be left alone. I don't know why `make menuconfig` would cause the build system to recompile everything, but I've read on here that that is what it would do.

The problem I see with not having the second avenue open to me is that if I change the configuration manually with a text editor, the options that I change might require changes in other options that depend on them (e.g., `IMA_TRUSTED_KEYRING` depends on `SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYRING`) and I'd be working without an interface that would automatically make those required secondary changes.

It occurred to me that invoking `scripts/kconfig/mconf`, the program built and launched by `make menuconfig`, could possibly be a solution to the problems described in the previous paragraph since it was not stated that `mconf` is what makes the build system recompile everything. But, it possibly could be that very program, so I do not wish to try it until I know it won't do that.

Sooooo, how does one achieve the stated objective given the stated scenario?

Comment: Your *"understanding"* is wrong, and you're overthinking the whole problem (which doesn't exist).  Do not manually edit the .config file, but do a `make menuconfig`.  Then based on what what has changed, the subsequent `make` will determine the minimal components to rebuild, and accomplish your goal.

Comment: What kind of change was made in config? Is it global option or just enabling some module?